# Dashicons not showed for admin menu

Tags: menus, admin-menu

**Wordpress version: 4.7.1**

I'm registering a classic custom pot type

```
 register_post_type ( 'products',  $products_args);
```

Where `$products_args` contains `menu_icon`

```
$products_args = array (
    ....
    'labels'    => array (
        ....
        'name'      => 'Prodotti',
        ....
    ),
    'menu-icon' => 'dashicons-cart',
    ....
);
```

Actually the admin menu for 'Products' is added, but the icon is alwyas fixed to the 'pin' (or 'post') icon

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found:

Simply replace

```
'menu-icon'
```

with

```
'menu_icon'
```